# Cannot connect to VLC RTSP server

Tags: amazon-ec2, video-streaming, vlc, rtsp

I am using AWS EC2 CentOS based system. I also have a website is running on it at the domain mydomain.com

I have installed VLC successfully for my server. I can do SSH and remote to my server (I can use GUI application with gnome)

I start the vlc server with the below command:

```
vlc --ttl 34 -vvv --color -I telnet --telnet-password vlc --rtsp-host 0.0.0.0 --rtsp-port=554
```

and setup the stream on it by:

```
root@whm [~]#  telnet localhost 4212
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower
Password:
Welcome, Master
> new sample01 vod enabled
new
> setup sample01 input file:///home/myuser/public_html/mywebsite/folder/video.mp4
setup
```

The output of the log is good.

```
[0x7f24a002c5b8] stream_out_rtp vod server debug: RTSP stream at /sample01
[0x7f24a002c5b8] main vod server debug: net: listening to 0.0.0.0 port 554
[0x7f24a002c5b8] stream_out_rtp vod server debug: RTSP: adding /sample01/trackID=0
[0x7f24a002c5b8] stream_out_rtp vod server debug: RTSP: adding /sample01/trackID=1 


[0x7fce4802d8c8] [Media: vod] main input debug: `file:///home/myuser/public_html/video.mp4' successfully opened
```

If I stay on the server it self, using GUI, I can use the VLC player to open network stream URL:

```
rtsp://localhost:554/sample01 (it works)
```

If I use vlc player from another network to connect to the stream by the below URL
`rtsp://mydomain.com:554/sample01` (this is the domain that is working for my website)

`rtsp://my-server-public-ip.com:554/sample01` (does not work too)

I guess there is something wrong with the port, then I went to AWS console and added more port 554 and 4212 into Inbound list in the Security Group of my instance (like what I'd done for other ports), but it does not help.

The error of the vlc client is:

```
[000000010050e4c8] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[000000010022a7e8] [http] lua interface: Lua HTTP interface
[0000000104a00978] live555 demux error: Failed to connect with rtsp://mydomain.com:554/sample01
[00000001002b2dc8] core access error: connection failed: Connection refused
[00000001002b2dc8] access_realrtsp access error: cannot connect to mydomain.com:554
[0000000100618e58] core input error: open of `rtsp://mydomain.com:554/sample01' failed
CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.
```

Please help me on this to troubleshoot this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem is solved. I have done following things to resolve it, but I am not sure which one is correct. If anyone got same issue, you could try one of these

1. I enable to Elastic Load Balance serivice of Amazon and add port fowarding for port 554 (RTSP default port)
2. The streaming server was running well on localhost on server itself but it is inaccessible from outside, I guess it is something about firewall and port.

I scan mydomain.com to see the port is open or not

```
nmap -v -Pn -sT mydomain.com
```

Temporarily disable firewall on AWS EC2 instance OR add a line into iptables to open port 554.
Open and edit file by

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

Add below line into it

```
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dpport 554 -j ACCEPT
```

or shutdown the firewall absotelutely

```
sudo service iptables save
sudo service iptables stop
sudo chkconfig iptables off
```

Optional, if you are using firewall of Cpanel, you have to check the same with the allowed port of that firewall.